# bessels equation

Tags: summation, bessel-functions

A long cylinder (radius $r = b$) initially at $T=f(r)$ is exposed to a cooling medium which extracts heat uniformly from its surface. It was assumed that heat transfer takes place only through radial direction.

From the research I did I could find out that the below is the analytical solution, for unsteady state heat transfer in an infinitely long cylinder along r direction.Using this analytical solution I need to find out the temperature time distribution at each time interval for all nodal points from surface to centre

$$T(r,t)=T_0+\frac{2}{b}(T_i-T_0)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\beta_m}\frac{\mathrm{J_1}(\beta_m\cdot b)\mathrm{J_0}(\beta_m\cdot r))}{\mathrm{J}_0^2(\beta_m\cdot b)+\mathrm{J}_1^2 (\beta_m\cdot b)} \exp\left(-\beta^2_m \cdot\alpha\cdot t\right)$$

$J_0$ is the Bessel function of first kind and $J_1=-J'_0$.

Where the eigenvalues $\beta_m$ are obtained from the roots of transcendental equation

$\beta\cdot b\cdot J_1(\beta\cdot b)-B_i\cdot J_0(\beta\cdot b)=0$ and $B_i,b,T_0,T_i,\alpha,r,t$ are known.

Is there any way I could generate numerical solution to the above equation?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! Your post is very difficult to read (at least for me)

Comment: use latex commands

Comment: See formatting instructions for mathematics: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Comment: I tried to translate to LaTeX, but it has to be checked.

Comment: Yeah That's the equation. Thanks.

Comment: Hem, this is not an equation!

Comment: Doesn't it boil down to solving the Eigen equation $aJ_0+bJ_1\beta=0$ ? This can probably be achieved by a similar process than that used to find the roots of the Bessel functions alone. For large roots, the asymptotic approximation will be helpful.